# Porque no me encuentra el control?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Estoy implementando como un wizard en el que hay un form Padre y dentro de este un panel que iran dentro dos UsersControl que sera el primero de ConfNotas y el otro NotasExplica. Lo que pasa es que estos componentes tenian otro nombre porque no tenia pensado uno definito y con la misma lógica funcionaba, ahora he cambiado a los nombres que os he puesto y me ha dejado de funcionar la aplicación.

En el Form Padre añado los dos usersControl dentro de un panel llamado pnlPrincipal, que en el ConfNotas hay un boton cerrar y otro de continuar que seria el encargado de mostrar el siguiente UserControl y el que me da error justamente. Y el segundo UsersControl tiene el boton de atras y finalizar.

```
    public FormInforme()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pnlPrincipal.Controls.Add(new ConfNotas());
        pnlPrincipal.Controls.Add(new NotasExplica());
    }
```

Al ejecutar la app me muestra el ConfNotas que en el boton continuar pasaria al siguiente:

```
    private void btnContinuar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Step().Forward(ParentForm, "pbImagenPrimera", "pbSegunaImagen", "NotasExplica");
    }
```

He creado una clase llamada Step que es la encargada de gestionar el tirar hacia atras o hacia delante y otras funcionalidades como mostrar x imagenes o otras.

```
public void Forward(Form formPadre, string pictureBoxActual, string imagenSiguiente, string formSiguiente) 
{
    //ACTUALIZA LA IMAGEN ACTUAL
    PictureBox imagenActual = (PictureBox)formPadre.Controls.Find(pictureBoxActual, false)[0];
    imagenActual.Image = Properties.Resources.completed;

    //CONFIGURA LA SIGUIENTE IMAGEN
    PictureBox siguienteImagen = (PictureBox)formPadre.Controls.Find(imagenSiguiente, false)[0];
    siguienteImagen.Image = Properties.Resources.current;

    //ACTUALIZA LA PAGINA
    formPadre.Controls.Find("pnlPrincipal", false)[0].Controls.Find(formSiguiente, false)[0].BringToFront();          
}

public void Back(Form formPadre, string pictureBoxActual, string imagenAnterior, string formAnterior)
{
    PictureBox imagenActual = (PictureBox)formPadre.Controls.Find(pictureBoxActual, false)[0];
    imagenActual.Image = Properties.Resources.pending;

    PictureBox siguienteImagen = (PictureBox)formPadre.Controls.Find(imagenAnterior, false)[0];
    siguienteImagen.Image = Properties.Resources.current;

    formPadre.Controls.Find("pnlPrincipal", false)[0].Controls.Find(formAnterior, false)[0].BringToFront();
}
```

Pero cada vez que doy click en el boton continuar y llama la función de la clase step forward me da error en esta línea diciendo que el indice estaba fuera de los límites de la matriz:

> formPadre.Controls.Find("pnlPrincipal",
> false)[0].Controls.Find(formSiguiente, false)[0].BringToFront();

Pero es que lo que no entiendo es que la lógica como tal no la cambie, solo cambie los nombres de los UsersControl a los ya mencionados y el programa simplemente no me los encuentra dentro del panel. He recompilado, cerrado y vuelto abrir el programa y nada. A que se deberia el error ? Porque en el panel me muestra que no hay ningún control adherido ?

Eso si, si hago un this.Hide() en el boton continuar ocultando el UserControl de ese momento se ve que el siguiente esta dentro del panel, por eso no entiendo que se me esta escapando o que he hecho mal.

He probado en hacer esto y en los messageBox me muestra los siguiente:

```
  var test = formPadre.Controls.Find("pnlPrincipal", false)[0].Controls;

        foreach(var controls in test)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(controls .ToString());
           
        }
```

Y me devuelve:
namespace.Forms.UsersControls.ConfNotas
namespace.Forms.UsersControls.NotasExplica

Osea si que estan insertados en el panel, pero si hago un find del panel sigue devolviendo como vacio.

Comment: Si solo has cambiado el nombres de tus clases, tu lógica no se verá afectada. Prueba a hacer un `Clean` del proyecto y un `Rebuild` del proyecto.

Comment: Tampoco funciona

Comment: En lugar de usar Find, puedes acceder directamente al control mediante uso de índices. Por ejemplo, prueba `((Form) formPadre.Controls["pnlPrincipal"].Controls[formAnterior]).BringToFront()`. Nota que he supuesto que la variable `formAnterior` es de tipo `string`.

Comment: Y yo pregunto.. debugueaste? te fijaste que formPadre.Controls tenga lo que buscas? te fijaste que dentro de eso, tengas lo que buscas? esto es un simple caso de que seguro, esta mal el nombre. pero no podemos ayudarte, porque no lo podemos debuguear nosotros.

Comment: Sisi, hice debug y el control pnlPrincipal lo pilla bien, pero al mirar dentro del pnlPrincipal no hay nada devuelve vació es como si no hubiera nada y es lo que no entiendo. Porque como se ve en el código

Comment: @nonameyet pruebo lo que me has comentado y te contesto si me ha funcionado o no ;D

Comment: En el método `btnContinuar_Click` puedes sustituir `ParentForm` por `this`... Suponiendo que los botones de avanzar y retroceder están en el formPadre (es decir la clase  `FormInforme`) y por tanto `this` hace referencia a formPadre.

Comment: @nonameyet no puedo hacer eso el btnContinuar es de la pantalla UsersControl no es formato Form como padre, igualmente me indica error diciendo eso mismo.

Comment: @nonameyet tambien he probado lo que me decias sin usar find, pero me da error en BringToFront diciendo que no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: Ya creo que lo entendí. La primera llamada a Controls.Find NO FALLA. La segunda llamada a Controls.Find SI FALLA, porque has añadido tus UserControls directamente a la colección Controls de tu pnlPrincipal. Entonces las variables "formAnterior" y "formSiguiente" no te sirven aquí

Comment: @nonameyet si, es el segundo controls que falla lo comente. Antes de cambiar el nombre de los UsersControls iba y aunque ponga el nombre que me devuelve en los foreach me sigue indicando error, edite la pregunta con lo que hice.